# there is any way to instantiate a new class based on enum?

Tags: vb.net, reflection, enums, instantiation

**there is any way to instantiate a new class based on enum through reflection?**

Basicly i wanna to remove the Select Case. I have alot of Enum and builders....

For example:

```
Public MustInherit Class GeneralClass
    '...

    Enum GeneralClassType
         A = 1
         B = 2
    End Enum

    Public Shared Function BuildClass(Val as Integer, ParamArray par() as Object) as GeneralClass
        Dim NewObject as GeneralClass = Nothing

        Select Case Ctype(Val, GeneralClassType)
              Case GeneralClassType.A
                   NewObject = new A 

              Case GeneralClassType.B
                   NewObject = new B

              Case else
                   throw new exception("invalid type.")

        end select

        NewObject.setPar(par)
        return NewObject
    end function
End Class

Public Class A
    Inherits GeneralClass
    '...
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits GeneralClass
    '...
End Class
```

The Function **BuildClass** build a class base on a type and parameters get from Database.
But i need to have the Case to create a new instance of a type.

I know i can instantiate a class through reflection, but only if you know the final type.
There is no way to do this dinamicy, like save the class name on database?

```
 public function InstantiateClass(of T)() as T
     Dim NewObject as GeneralClass = GetType(T).GetConstructor(New Type() {}).Invoke(New Object() {})
     return NewObject
 end class
```

than i can get something like

```
Dim Var1 as GeneralClass = InstantiateClass(of A)()
```

and use this instance inside the Build function. But here i need to know the Type **A**

> ---
>
> **BaseTest example, working with enum name.**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim BaseFlag As Integer = 2
        Dim BaseName As String = "Create a class from enum"


        Dim T As BaseTest = BaseTest.Build(BaseFlag, BaseName)
        MsgBox(T.GetClassTypeName)
    End Sub

End Class

Public MustInherit Class BaseTest
    Protected Name As String

    Enum TestType
        TestA = 1
        TestB = 2
        TestC = 3
    End Enum

    Public Function GetClassTypeName() As String
        Return String.Concat(Name, ". The final class is: ", Me.GetType.FullName, "")
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Build(BaseFlag As Integer, Name As String) As BaseTest
        Dim NS As String = GetType(BaseTest).FullName
        Dim Index As Integer = NS.LastIndexOf(".") + 1
        NS = NS.Substring(0, Index)

        Dim ClassType As String = CType(BaseFlag, TestType).ToString()
        Dim Test As BaseTest = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(NS & ClassType))

        Test.Name = Name
        Return Test
    End Function
End Class

Public Class TestB
    Inherits BaseTest

End Class
```

Comment: Going with reflection to save on typing may not always be the right decision. If you have a lot of repetitive code, you should reconsider your design. Reflection only seems to be easier. You are looking to have a lot of maintenance nightmare in the long run. Unless you have justified the move, of course.

Comment: I'm using reflection because i don't know another way to do this.
The point is, soon i'm going to have alot of enum for all flags in my base.

This flags determine one way to flow or another. So to avoid a lot of class that has the same code, a made some generic class, and specific class for specific ways, reducing a lot the number of class and maintenance.

The old code was full of " Dim ob as New EspecificClass", with no superclass, than call some method that are not specific.. Ok, now i have to worry only with the builder and not with all " Dim ob as New EspecificClass".

Comment: It seems like you are branching workflows, i.e. there is a constant (or limited, better to say) set of steps, while the link between them is dynamic. Did you consider table-driven design?

Comment: Never work with "table-driven design" before, but i gonna check this. Thanks.

Comment: You may find these links useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42732/Table-driven-Approach and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_table, to set you on terminology (and ideas for further googling).

Comment: in my personal opinion, i think " ObjectName.DoStuff " is much more easier to maintain rather than a formula like " price += (daysRented - initialDays[movie_type]) * multiplier[movie_type]; ". Thinking about a new person get this code to read. But thanks for sharing this approach.

Comment: This is why you have encapsulation and abstraction. Give a name to `initialDays[movie_type]` (a property), then `daysRented - that property`, etc. You end up with a very readable code. Right now I have no idea what `initialDays[movie_type]` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to figure out how to get reflection to create an object instance given the class name as a string.  Here's an example of one way to do that:

```
Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyNameSpace.A"))
```

Once you have that working, all you need to do is to get the string name of the enumeration value.  To do that, all you need to do is to call the `ToString` method on the enumeration object, for instance, in your case:

```
Dim className As String = CType(Val, GeneralClassType).ToString()
```

Once you have that, you can simply concatenate the class name to the namespace to create the object:

```
Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("MyNameSpace." & className))
```

The example you posted is type-safe, whereas using reflection, like this, is not.  Also, reflection can be a bit slower.  You need to decide, based on your particular situation, whether or not it is worth giving up that type-safety and efficiency.

Comment: i'm gonna test it and post later. Thanks!

Comment: In fact this Works. The class name must by the name of the enum, but Works fine!  I'm gonna update the question with this answer.

Comment: *"The class name must have the name of the enum"*. Now need one enum and class for each specific action. That what i'm was looking for, no need to maintain all the code. Just the specific class and yours enum.